# twitteR package installation failure

Tags: r, twitter, package

Hi I'm trying to install `twitteR` package but it is giving error. Previous version I got the same error so I uninstalled it and re installed R again. But I am facing the same problem again. Can some one help me please. Thanks in advance.

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rjson)
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl’
ERROR: dependency ‘RCurl’ is not available for package ‘ROAuth’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ROAuth’
ERROR: dependencies ‘ROAuth’, ‘RCurl’ are not available for package ‘twitteR’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/twitteR’
```

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpeTWabe/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:

```
1: In install.packages("twitteR", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("twitteR", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘ROAuth’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("twitteR", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘twitteR’ had non-zero exit status
> library(twitteR)
Error in library(twitteR) : there is no package called ‘twitteR’
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2013                        
month          09                          
day            25                          
svn rev        63987                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
nickname       Frisbee Sailing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Install `twitteR` package, it will automatically try to install `ROauth` (since it's a suggested package), which depends on `liboauth`. You can download `liboauth` from http://liboauth.sourceforge.net.

Install `Rcurl`:

```
$sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

you can do in similar terms.Install an R package from the Linux command line. Let's say we would like to install the "likelihood" R package. you can download it by:

```
$ wget -q http://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/likelihood_1.5.tar.gz
```

Next we use the `R CMD INSTALL` command to install it. Please note that depending on the installation destination you may need to have a superuser privileges:

```
    $ sudo R CMD INSTALL likelihood_1.5.tar.gz 
[sudo] password for lubos: 
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘likelihood’ ...
** package ‘likelihood’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** demo
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (likelihood)
```

**NOTE:** Be aware that some packages will require prerequisites. In that case use the above command to install prerequisites prior to your desired package.

Comment: nitk@nitk-OptiPlex-9010:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for nitk: 
root@nitk-OptiPlex-9010:/home/nitk# wget -q http://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/liboauth_1.5.tar.gz
root@nitk-OptiPlex-9010:/home/nitk# sudo R CMD INSTALL liboauth_1.5.tar.gz
Warning: invalid package ‘liboauth_1.5.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
root@nitk-OptiPlex-9010:/home/nitk#

Comment: I have edited my post for `likelihood` package- load your package accordingly.

Comment: Here I have not installed the curl package hence I was unable to install Rcurl.

$sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

After installing curl I was successful in installing twitteR 

Thank you :)

Comment: Edit ur answer with the command including curl installation that i hav mentioned in my prev comment :)

Comment: I had to also install libssl-dev using 
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`